# Render body error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
<body>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Alerts1"); }
        @RenderBody()

        <hr />
      </div>
    </body>
```

ERROR

An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.WebPages.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The file "~/Views/Client/Index.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderBody" method.

Comment: `RenderBody()` belongs to Master/Layout pages

Comment: how do i go about solving this problem new to mvc

Comment: See http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui,-layouts,-and-themes/3-creating-a-consistent-look

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP MVC Trying to load layout from string Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918785/asp-mvc-trying-to-load-layout-from-string-model)